# How do I generate JKS keystore (server side) file that conforms to TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384?

Tags: ssl, keystore, jks

I know about TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384. But, how can i generate JKS keystore file choosing these algorithms, can you please recommend a tool?

I explored Keystore Explorer GUI tool but it does not allow to choose all the algorithms. Please recommend a GUI tool or command line.

Comment: No TLS cert (ever) selects a single ciphersuite, but to _enable_ that one and several others in 1.2 you need an EC key&cert, which keystore explorer CAN create according to its website. So can commandline `keytool -genkeypair -keytype ec ...`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below command in cmd to generate key pair for jks file.

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore filename.keystore -keypass domainname.com -storepass domainname.com -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -alias server -deststoretype pkcs12
```

Comment: No.  The question specifically asks for a certificate and private key that can be used for a server to support the `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` cipher suite.  That requires an EC certificate.  This answer will generate an ***RSA*** certificate and doesn't answer the question.